# Accessing class in static java method

Tags: java, static

We have self registering subclasses of 'Handler' which we want to access through Subclass.me(). Is something similar to this possible in Java: ?

```
public class Handler{
static Vector<Handler> register=new Vector<Handler>();
public static Handler me() {
        return register.get( this.class);// TODO
}
}

public class SubClass extends Handler{
     SubClass(){register.add(this);}// OK
}
```

To clarify the question: Is it possible to retrieve the CLASS when calling a static java method? this.class obviously doesn't work, because 'this' is not available.

Answer (score 4):

Static methods belong to the class. They cannot be overridden.

```
MyClass.myStaticMethod()
```

is the only correct way of accessing a static method.

Comment: They don't need to be overwritten, but the second part answers the question. 
If MyClass.myStaticMethod() is the only correct way, how come calling Subclass.myStaticMethod() does not even give a warning in eclipse??

Comment: @Anno2001 Eclipse lets you choose if you want to get an error/warning or ignore non-static access to a static member.
Look under Eclipse preferences, Java —> Compiler —> Errors/Warnings —> Code Style —> Non-static access to static member.

Answer (score 0):

In java, you cannot make a static reference to the non-static method/variable. So,

- If you want to access a non-static method / variable then you must
  create an instance of the class first.
- If you are going to access a static method / variable then you can
  access it directly through the class name without creating a
  instance.

Because, the static method and variable are belong to the Class not to the Instance while the non-static method and variable are belong to the Instance not to the Class.